# CRUD operations on a table with foreign key on same table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have created a table tree with parent child relationship using laravel migration like this:

```
class CreateTableTree extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('trees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('has_child');
            $table->integer('depth');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('trees')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('trees');
    }
}
```

I want to get nested collection from data in table. I have a model Tree for above table.

For test purpose, I want to insert some data using seeder like this:

```
public function run()
    {
        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
            $one = new Tree();
            $one->parent_id=0;
            $one->name = 'One'.$i;
            $one->has_child=1;
            $one->depth=0;
            $one->save(); 
            for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
                $two = new Tree();
                $two->parent_id=$one->id;
                $two->name = 'One'.$i.'Two'.$j;
                $two->has_child=1;
                $two->depth=1;
                $two->save(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

when I run the seeder through artisan command. I've got following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                        
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`website`.`trees`,  
CONSTRAINT `trees_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `trees` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `trees` (`p arent_id`, `name`, `has_child`, `depth`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, One0, 1, 0, 2017-05-27 16:29:40, 2017-05-27 16:29:40))
```

I can't figure out where I am doing wrong ?
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query fails because there is no ID = 0 in the table, so you need to make `parent_id` field nullable:

```
$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Then you'll be able to keep it empty, just remove this line:

```
$one->parent_id = 0;
```

Comment: @Sagar did you recreated the table? If yes, what error do you get now?

Comment: I've some syntax error over there as well and finally worked. Thank you

Comment: I'm waiting for asking time to reach 5min so that I can accept answer